# Clear animation from the :before pseudo element

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I have an animation for links and have one link with a pseudo element that creates content before the link. However, this pseudo content should (a) not serve as clickable link and (b) the animation should not extend to it.

I've tried everything I could think of but couldn't solve it.

Can anyone help me?

```css
a {
  color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 0 #141414, 0.08em 0 0 #fff, 0 0, -0.08em 0 0 #fff;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

a:after {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1))) center 1.08em/100% 2px no-repeat;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)) center 1.08em/100% 2px no-repeat;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 400%;
  will-change: transform;
  z-index: -1;
}

a:hover::after {
  -webkit-animation: underline-gradient 6s linear infinite;
  animation: underline-gradient 6s linear infinite;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(15%, rgba(122, 95, 255, 0.8)), color-stop(35%, rgba(1, 255, 137, 0.6)), color-stop(85%, rgba(122, 95, 255, 0.8)));
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(122, 95, 255, 0.8) 15%, rgba(1, 255, 137, 0.6) 35%, rgba(122, 95, 255, 0.8) 85%);
}

@-webkit-keyframes underline-gradient {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-75%, 0%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-75%, 0%, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes underline-gradient {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-75%, 0%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-75%, 0%, 0);
  }
}

a::before {
  content: '| \a0\a0 \0020';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  background-image: none !important;
  background: none !important;
  transform: none !important;
  transition-property: none !important;
  animation: none !important;
}

a:hover::before {
  content: '| \a0\a0 \0020';
  color: red;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  background-image: none !important;
  background: none !important;
  transform: none !important;
  transition-property: none !important;
  animation: none !important;
}
```

```html
<span style="font-size:50px">
Here is a <br><br><a href="#">link</a> <br><br>as an example.
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Pseudo content should not serve as clickable link***

For this you have to set `position:absolute` and negative `left` and `pointer-events:none` to the pseudo element. And also `margin-left` to the `<a>` tag.

***The animation should not extend to pseudo content***

For this you have to use a `<span>` tag for the linear background animation. Apply `overflow:hidden` to this `<span>` instead of `<a>`

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$("a.link").append("<span></span>")
```

```css
a {
  color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 0 #141414, 0.08em 0 0 #fff, 0 0, -0.08em 0 0 #fff;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

a>span {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

a span:after {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1))) center 1.08em/100% 2px no-repeat;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)) center 1.08em/100% 2px no-repeat;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 400%;
  will-change: transform;
  z-index: -1;
}

a:hover span::after {
  -webkit-animation: underline-gradient 6s linear infinite;
  animation: underline-gradient 6s linear infinite;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(15%, rgba(122, 95, 255, 0.8)), color-stop(35%, rgba(1, 255, 137, 0.6)), color-stop(85%, rgba(122, 95, 255, 0.8)));
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(122, 95, 255, 0.8) 15%, rgba(1, 255, 137, 0.6) 35%, rgba(122, 95, 255, 0.8) 85%);
}

@-webkit-keyframes underline-gradient {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-75%, 0%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-75%, 0%, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes underline-gradient {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-75%, 0%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-75%, 0%, 0);
  }
}

a::before {
  content: '| \a0\a0 \0020';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  background-image: none !important;
  background: none !important;
  transform: none !important;
  transition-property: none !important;
  animation: none !important;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

a:hover::before {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<span style="font-size:50px">
Here is a <br><br><a class="link" href="#">link</a><br><br>as an example.
```

Comment: thank you very much! Unfortunatley, the menu comes out from wordpress, so I cannot add a <span>. I only have access to the css class of each menu item. Is there any other solution that work with that restriction?

Comment: @AlphaX you can add span tag using jQuery...because as I tried so many ways your both points can't be fixed in your markup...

Comment: @AlphaX I have updated my answer for adding a `span` tag using jQuery